# XIB doesn't load... just shows a black screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

I'm creating a universal application in iOS 4.2 and above.

I have a nib called `DataInputViewController_iPhone.xib`. On the first view controller which comes up I have a button which should launch the class `DataInputViewController`. It does it, but it doesn't show the contents of the XIB file. It just shows a black screen.

Any ideas why this happens?

I have this code which calls the new view controller:

```
-(IBAction)clickedButton:(id)sender {
    if((UIButton *)sender == (UIButton *)startButton){
        NSString *nibName;
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            nibName = @"DataInputViewController_iPhone";
        } else {
            nibName = @"DataInputViewController_iPad";
        }

        DataInputViewController *nextVC = [[DataInputViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
    }
    else if((UIButton *)sender == (UIButton *)otherButton){
        NSLog(@"clicked the other button");
    }
}
```

NSLogging in this method and in the `init` method of the new view controller tells me that the `nibNameOrNil` variable is pulled through correctly.

This is what the (standard) init method looks like in `DataInputViewController.m`:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Or how to fix?

Thanks :)

Comment: have you, by any chance, implemented the function loadView inside your DataInputViewController?

Comment: If you look in the XIB file for the data input view controller, I am guessing that there is a UIView as the root element of that XIB. Check to make sure that the File's Owner view is hooked up to that root element. (I thought you would get a warning or error if this were the case, but I could be wrong. You aren't getting any errors or warnings in the console after you press the button, are you?)

Comment: go to project > build Phases > copy bundle resources and make sure that your xib is there.

Comment: @Niko no I haven't. And I've called `[super ...]` in any overridden methods.

Comment: @bp There are no errors, its all working fine. As far as I can tell the view is connected to the file's owner.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi all there... strange! :)

Comment: yes thats really strange because I always use this way and its work fine ! can you please try to load the iPad one and see whats happened ?

Comment: The ipad one doesn't have anything in. I've had to work around it and just create a new view controller with nibs which seems to work fine! Very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to fix this is to delete the nibs and class and then recreate them. Not particularly elegant, but it works ...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to manually set up the nib name.  Just name them `DataInputViewController~iphone.xib` and `DataInputViewController~ipad.xib`, then call `[[DataInputViewController alloc] init]`.

See [iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW2) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately it hasn't worked. Still a black screen.

Comment: iOS has a case-sensitive filesystem.  Is the case of your nib files correct?

Comment: class file: `DataInputViewController` xib file: `DataInputViewController~iPhone` I believe they're fine. Is the end bit ok?

Comment: No.  Use the case specified in my answer.

Comment: Aha! I see... little p... I will try that.

Comment: Makes no difference. And it wouldn't let me rename iPhone to iphone as it said that file already existed. (I got round it by changing the name completely and renaming)

Comment: Yes, that's because OS X doesn't have a case-sensitive filesystem.  Check that the file owner for the nibs is set correctly.

Comment: This (as I have recently found) is a good tip for when you build to phone. In simulator it doesn't make a difference and my problem was in the simulator. But thanks for the tip, without this I'd have been stuck when I ran it on device! haha

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just clean your project, close XCode, reboot your Mac and open project again.
And don't forget delete app on simulator or device previously.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue where I needed to load either iPad or iPhone .xib files for a utility view controller. It is a form so it had a lot of UILabel and UITextField elements that were linked as IBOutlets. I would construct the entire layout, link all of the elements, and it worked fine until when I built and ran it. I even took the advice posted on this thread and re-created both .xib's and the class files (a great deal of linking IBOutlets) with no success.

The problem was this. The root view cannot be @synthesized in the implementation of the class. As soon as I synthesized the base view, everything went black. By simply removing the "@synthesize view;" line, everything worked like a charm. When I presented my view controller everything was there again.

Here is the header file for the class with all of the IBOutlets:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SignUpFormViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *rootView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *signUpFormLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterEmailLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterEmailTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterPasswordLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterPasswordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *reEnterPasswordLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *reEnterPasswordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterFirstNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterFirstNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterLastNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterLastNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterPhoneNumberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterPhoneNumberTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterStreetAddressLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterStreetAddressTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterStreetAddress2Label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterStreetAddress2TextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterCityLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterCityTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterStateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterStateTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *enterZipLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enterZipTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *signUpNowButton;

- (IBAction)infoButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)signUpNowButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is the implementation file with the root view being synthesized:

```
#import "SignUpFormViewController.h"

@implementation SignUpFormViewController
@synthesize rootView,signUpFormLabel,infoButton,enterEmailLabel,enterEmailTextField,enterPasswordLabel,enterPasswordTextField,reEnterPasswordLabel,reEnterPasswordTextField,enterFirstNameLabel,enterFirstNameTextField,enterLastNameLabel,enterLastNameTextField,enterPhoneNumberLabel,enterPhoneNumberTextField,enterStreetAddressLabel,enterStreetAddressTextField,enterStreetAddress2Label,enterStreetAddress2TextField,enterCityLabel,enterCityTextField,enterStateLabel,enterStateTextField,enterZipLabel,enterZipTextField,backButton,signUpNowButton,btnDone,btnPrev,btnNext,inputAccView,activeTextField,currentString;
```

Simply remove the "rootView" from the list of properties being synthesized and this should fix the problem. Much easier than deleting the .xib files for BOTH iPad and iPhone layouts and re-creating them.

FYI I am using xCode 4.6.3 with target SDK = 6.1

I hope this helps anybody else that experiences this time-consuming and very frustrating issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: delete your app on the simulator or device and run again. I find if I twiddle with nibs too much, especially around names or localization, it appears that everything works (I get no errors), but Xcode is actually ignoring the changes.

So perform a Clean (**Product->Clean**), delete from simulator or device, run again.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did this many times, but to no avail. :/ There must have been something broken or wrong somewhere. I've just recreated the classes and nibs now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to implement the loadView method in your DataInputViewController.m and inside the method add the line [super loadView], like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that not dragging an outlet from the File Owner to your custom sub-classed UITableViewCell.h or .m file can cause the blackness as well. Make sure that you drag an outlet to one of the two files associated with your sub-class of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 
I was receive xib file from co-worker.
well loaded xib but did not shown.
spent all my one a day because Hidden checkbox was checked

check Hidden checkbox in xib.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Fix!!
Navigating to version editor and back to standard editor fixed the problem for me